# Why can’t I hear notifications on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, notifications

Sound is on:

<sup>Click for full size</sup>
[image] [image] [image]

I'm testing the notification sound with Gmail. Gmail notifications are on:

[image]

Why can’t I hear notifications on my iPhone?

I can't hear any notifications from any apps. However, I can see notifications. Also, the media sound works eg if I go on YouTube on Chrome, I can hear the videos.

I use an iphone 12 mini with iOS 15.7.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the silent mode was activated. Here's how to switch the silent mode on and off:

[image]